# QGIS Memory Usage Eventually Crashes Program

Tags: qgis-3

I am using the long-term release of QGIS (3.4.12). When I first start the program, it takes up about 625MB of memory. After I have been working with it for several hours, the memory usage often increases up to 15GB, and everything on the computer becomes sluggish. I have 16GB of memory in my computer. When it becomes sluggish, I have to save everything because if I continue past this point, QGIS usually crashes shortly thereafter. Even if I can close the project I am working on, the memory usage doesn't change. When I then try to exist QGIS, it hangs up, and I have to kill it using the Task Manager.

Is there a reason why the memory usage climbs so significantly and stays high? Is there anyway to reclaim it without exiting the project and the program?

In response to comments, yes, the memory was off by an order of magnitude. 625,000KB to start, and 15GB after using for a while. 16GB computer memory. The installed plugins are DB Manager, Geometry Checker, Georeferencer GDAL, GPS Tools, Lat Lon Tools, Meta Search Catalog Client, Processing, and Topology Checker. I haven't really paid a whole lot of attention to what I was specifically working on when it crashed, but the last time I had been working on something and it crashed, I had been using "Offset lines" and "Split Parts" and "Merge Features". I haven't just left the program open without doing any analysis, but I doubt if doing this would result in any increased memory usage.

Operating system is Windows 7.

**Update 03 Feb 2020:** Still having the same problem. I haven't been able to identify one particular tool or action that causes it. The memory usage just climbs until it is about 15GB. Even if I close the project, the memory usage remains high (see screenshot)[image: screenshot]

If I try to exit QGIS, it just becomes unresponsive, and I have to kill the program in Task Manager. There is never a graceful exit. I have to be careful to save every so often or I will lose everything I have been working on. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that your memory usage aren't off an order of magnitude (K to M, M to G)?

Comment: Does this happen no matter what you're working on? What if you just leave the program open and don't do any analysis? What kinds of tools are you using? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Also on what operating system are you on ?

Comment: I've seen incredibly high memory usage when working with large featuresets stored in ESRI FileGeoDatabases. When I convert these same data to something like GeoPackage, I can edit/process/view with ease and without the memory usage climbing until the computer becomes unresponsive.

Here's my GitHub issue concerning this:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30225

Comment: Could you try updating to QGIS 3.4.15-1 LTS to see if the behavior changes at all?
https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.15-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: Seems like a buggy plugin installed. Try with a new profile: _Settings ~> User Profiles ~> New Profile_.